# TMS TWebCopy, Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tms

I have TMS TWebCopy 2.3 on Delphi 2010.

When i try to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.WebCopy1Error(Sender: TObject; ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
showmessage('Error '+inttostr(ErrorCode));
end;
```

and

```
 with webcopy1.items.add do
    begin
     url:='http://zcvhxhjcgv.com/asdfsag.zip';  //fictional url, error must appear
     targetdir:=tgt.text;
    end;
```

I have NOT get any errors! When I try to download 5-10 files WebCopy can notify 1 time, but anothers - NO.
WebCopy creates empty files with names from URL with sizes 921, 935 bytes.

The same situation for `TForm1.WebCopy1ErrorInfo`, `TForm1.WebCopy1URLNotFound`, `TForm1.WebCopy1ConnectError`.
I have written to support center of TMS, I do not know they reply me with any suggestion or not.

Comment: does this version of the component support unicode? If not then you'll need to buy an upgrade from TMS or work out how to port it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source, Delphi might be recompiling the TWebCopy.
Implicitly substituting all strings from AnsiStrings into WideStrings.

**Make a backup.**
And replace all `string`'s into `Ansistring` in the source of TWebCopy.
Recompile and see if that helps.

or
Find the original DCU of TWebCopy and put the TWebCopy source out of harms way
and let Delphi use the original DCU, instead of the recompiled Widestringed DCU.